# I can't to do update

Tags: server, 22.04, error-handling

Recently I installed the ubuntu 22.04 but i treat problem with update.Especially as you can see in the next photo the minimum time is 10 hours.After 10 hours i see that didn't update and the time is the same.I tried to solve this with "Software & Updates" but the "Download from" drop-down menu" and it say that "There is no add-ons currently installed for this up".What else can i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmBn0.png)

Comment: Check date and time in OS and Bios/Uefi.

Comment: Internet time is UTC and your clock is wrong... As @nobody said, check your date/time & location (regional settings esp. timezone) as your clock is 11.5 hours wrong  (if its not date/time then it's your timezone/region being set incorrectly)

Comment: You are right.This was my problem.Thanks both of you for your help!